# Proper use of where in mysql?

Tags: mysql, where-clause

I am beginning to study php and my sql.

I don't know what is wrong with this code.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl where field1 (1,2,3)");
```

I am getting this error.

```
Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in test.php on line 52
```

When I replace that particular line with this

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl");
```

It works fine but it returns all rows.

I am trying to filter the rows display using where command in mysql.

What is the proper syntax for that?

Thanks

Comment: No reason for the -1. You are just missing the word "IN" in between field1 and (1,2,3)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need an `IN` clause:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl where field1 IN (1,2,3)");
```

This query is analogous to:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl where field1=1 OR field1=2 OR field1=3
```

**Also**, please keep in mind `mysql_query` has been [deprecated](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) and its use is discouraged.

Comment: Thanks.I am trying to accept your answer but it says I can accept in 4 minutes. I will try again later.

Comment: It was probably downvoted because It doesn't say anything about `mysql_*` functions being deprecated (or close to it) and perpetuating the future million posts about it not working instead of teaching people the alternatives (`mysqli` or `PDO`) now so that their applications don't break in future mysql updates...

Comment: Ah, I was looking at this more as a SQL question and less of a PHP question.  However, I'll update my answer.

Comment: @justin if that is deprecated, what is the new equivalent method for that?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl where field1 IN (1,2,3)");
```

Answer (score 0):

First off.. stop using the mysql extension as it's deprecated...

Aside from that, you do something like this:

`$result = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE field IN (1,2,3)");`

And here are a few other examples that aren't exactly for your case...

`$result = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE date BETWEEN "2012-06-01 00:00:00" AND "2012-06-12 23:59:59");`

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/where-optimizations.html will give you some information on the WHERE clause itself and how to properly utilize and optimize it..

Hope it helps.

Comment: the functions `mysql_*` (`mysql_query`, `mysql_num_rows`, `mysql_select_db`, etc.) are deprecated functions (or close to it), so it's best practice to use the alternates there are... such as `mysqli` or `PDO`...

Comment: i tried changing mysql_ with mysqli_ and now I get errors? do you have any resource for syntax of mysqli?

Comment: the syntax is the same...  But everything has to be done in mysqli_ if you switch to it (this means the mysql_connect needs to be mysqli_connect, etc)...  Then it should work....  

Though here is a little info on it, keep in mind i googled "mysqli syntax" and this is the first result --I looked at it briefly, but there might be better options..

http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/54239-introduction-to-mysqli-and-prepared-statements/

Comment: thanks. I will try it. The problem with google is it doesn't tell me if its deprecated or not. I actually googled how to  use php and mysql hand in hand and it gave me the syntax i am asking in this topic. It just breaks me knowing it is deprecated after having series of test making it work. Thanks for pointing out that it is deprecated.

Comment: Not a problem....  I'd much rather you learn the approved ways than old deprecated ways so that when php/mysql updates come out you don't come running to find out why it doesn't work....  I personally use PDO, i love it -- worth looking into...